# How to copy files from Yun to local computer?

Tags: arduino-yun

I would like to copy a file that is in the root folder of my Yun, to my Macbook. They are connected with an ethernet cable and I am logged into the Yun through ssh.
The Yun's IP is 192.168.2.16 while the Mac's is 192.168.2.1.

How can I copy a file from the Yun?

Once I tried to copy a file from the Macbook to the Yun using "scp" and it worked, but now I don't know how to do for the other direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply reverse the arguments.  Whatever you used to copy a file *to* the Yun you just do the opposite to copy *from* the Yun.

For instance, if you copied to the Yun using:

```
scp /my/local/file root@192.168.2.16:/where/you/want/it
```

Then you would change it around to copy from the Yun thus:

```
scp root@192.168.2.16:/path/to/file /where/you/want/it/to/go
```